# Where is the Alert Me Icon Location?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, ribbon, list-form

A Bit of backstory:  Client wants to replace the alert me button with a custom action, but retain the icon. Which is fine, accept I'm at a loss as to where this icon lives; it doesn't appear to be in the mapped images folder under 1033, nor anywhere else I've looked.

Any thoughts?

[image: Alert Me Icon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That image is part of an image sprite (where you have one image file containing many images) included in these two files:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\IMAGES\formatmap16x16.png

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\IMAGES\formatmap32x32.png

Comment: I found this about three minutes ago.  Kudos for deciphering my rather vague question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a alertme.png in the

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES
```

folder... not sure if thats the same one...